# node-telegram-bot-api и SpookyJS

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram, casperjs

При выполнении команды бота необходимо сделать парсинг сайта и потом вывести в чат сообщение. Сайт парсится с использованием casperjs. В nodejs casperjs работает через spookyjs.

Вот код выполнения команды бота:

```
bot.onText(/\/get_users_group (.+)/, (msg, [source, group]) => {
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `Начинаем парсить группу ${group}`);
    result = command_getUsersGroup.start(group);
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, result);
});
```

сообщение в чат отправляется до выполнения

```
command_getUsersGroup.start(group);
```

т.е. в консоле вижу что casperjs выполняет операции, переход по ссылкам, ожидание селектора, а сообщение в чат уже отправляется, при этом возникает ошибка что текст пустой, т.к. result = undefined.

Как сделать отправку в чат только после того как будет выполнена

```
result = command_getUsersGroup.start(group);
```

и result получит значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал следующим образом.

```
bot.onText(/\/get_users_group (.+)/, (msg, [source, group]) => {
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `Начинаем парсить группу ${group}`);
    command_getUsersGroup.start(bot, msg, group);
});
```

При получении команды от бота, выводим сообщение о начале операции, затем в фукнцию передаем бота, сообщение и другие параметры.

В функции command_getUsersGroup.start пишем

```
spooky.then(function() {
   const data = {};
   data.a = 1;
   data.b = 2;
   this.emit('asd', data);
});
```

и вешаем слушателя события asd

```
spooky.on('asd', function(a) {
   console.log("****************");
   console.log(helpers.debug(a));
   bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, helpers.debug(a));
});
```

Получается что на последнем шаге casperjs вызывает слушателя и посылает полученные данные в телеграм.

Не знаю насколько это правильно и грамотно, но работает и пока удовлетворяет моей задаче.